# Tweepy - Instead of getting the Url shared in the twitter I'm getting the tweet link?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

Below is my code.

Written in Python V3

```
import tweepy

consumer_key="***"
consumer_secret="***"
access_key="***"
access_secret="***"

TweetCollection={}

def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    alltweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name, count = 20, include_entities = True)

    for tweet in alltweets:
        Id=tweet.id_str
        PublishedAt=str(tweet.created_at)
        Tweet=unescape(tweet.text)
        ScreenName=screen_name
        if tweet.entities['urls']!=[]:
            StoryUrl=tweet.entities['urls'][0].get('url')
        else:
            StoryUrl=None
        if Id is not None:
            TweetCollection[Id]={'Tweet': Tweet, 'ScreenName': ScreenName, 'StoryUrl': StoryUrl, 'PublishedAt': PublishedAt}



get_all_tweets('SportIndustry')
print(TweetCollection={})
```

I need "t.co/PNMCqmC9Nw" but Im getting "t.co/PQwP3WoSGL"

Why? and what I should do to rectify the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way by changing a parameter.

```
alltweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name, count = 20, include_entities = True, tweet_mode='extended')
```

and also

```
Tweet=unescape(tweet.full_text)
```

Comment: Where is "unescape" defined?   "NameError: name 'unescape' is not defined"

Comment: use this import statement

`from html import unescape`